# Dont want to execute Update if Insert has not been executed

Tags: sql, sql-server

****Query*****************************
I have one stored procedure which has got one update and one insert query.
Update happens into say Table1 and Insert happens say Table2.I dont want to execute update if insert query fails due to any reason and vice versa.
Please tell me how to implement this.What I understand is I might have to use try catch and begin and end tran and rollback but not able to understand how to implement that.

---

Have just researched how to write Try and catch and begin tran and end it.

****************Stored Procedure*******************************************

```
 INSERT INTO @TempVariable(DUNS_Request_ID ,DUNS_Transaction_ID,DUNS_Status_ID)

SELECT T1.DUNS_Request_ID,T2.DUNS_Transaction_ID,DUNS_Status_ID
FROM   DUNS_Request_Master T1 
       LEFT JOIN DUNS_Transactions T2 ON T1.DUNS_Request_ID=T2.DUNS_Request_ID
WHERE  T1.DUNS_Request_ID IN 
      (SELECT DUNS_Request_ID FROM DUNS_Transactions WHERE DUNS_Status_ID = 2)
       AND CONVERT(DATE,RequestedDate) <= DATEADD(DAY, -1,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()))

UPDATE DUNS_Transactions 
SET    
       AssignedToUser_ID              = @ContentUserID
      ,DUNS_Status_ID                 = @FreeDUNSStatusID
      ,DUNS_Transaction_Update_Status = 'Automatic Conversion to Free DUNS'
      ,ProcessedDateTime              = GETDATE()

WHERE DUNS_Request_ID IN (SELECT DUNS_Request_ID FROM @TempVariable)

INSERT INTO    [DUNS_Transaction_Details]
               (
                DUNS_Request_ID,
                DUNS_Transaction_ID,
                DUNS_Status_ID,
                AssignedToUser_ID,
                AssignedByUser_ID,
                Comments,
                CommentsBy,
                CommentDate,
                ProcessedDateTime,
                IsActive
                )
        SELECT  DUNS_Request_ID,
                DUNS_Transaction_ID,
                @FreeDUNSStatusID,
                @ContentUserID,
                NULL,
                'Automatic Conversion to Free DUNS',
                NULL,
                GETDATE(),
                GETDATE(),
                1
        FROM    @TempVariable
```

Comment: you have two insert, for which insert fail you don't wanna execute update query ?? If insert fail for the table variable then update & insert both statement will not be executed and so, I think you already have that what you want.

Comment: hey Susang, its for second insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your research is correct:

Its going to be

```
Begin Try
    Begin Tran
        Query 1
        Query 2
    Commit Tran
End Try
Begin Catch
    Rollback
End catch
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also shift the `update` logic below the `insert` and join `DUNS_Transaction_Details` with unique conbination data which is just inserted to check if insert is success or not

```
UPDATE DT SET    
    AssignedToUser_ID = @ContentUserID
    ,DUNS_Status_ID = @FreeDUNSStatusID
    ,DUNS_Transaction_Update_Status = 'Automatic Conversion to Free DUNS'
    ,ProcessedDateTime = GETDATE()
FROM DUNS_Transactions  DT
INNER JOIN @TempVariable T ON T.DUNS_Request_ID = DT.DUNS_Request_ID
--Below join will check if insert is success - Join with unique columns
INNER JOIN DUNS_Transaction_Details DTD ON DTD.DUNS_Request_ID = T.DUNS_Request_ID 
    AND DTD.DUNS_Transaction_ID = T.DUNS_Transaction_ID 
--You can add more columns in the join to make it unique combination
```

Comment: If I shift update logic below insert and if insert fails then update will not take place only....That can also be one of the solution. But I want to maintain the order of sql scripts as that describes the business functionality clearly.

Comment: I can't say the `order of sql scripts` in your case but it would more clear and seems in order if you shift the update logic after insert but wish is yours :) However, to make it more clear you can use `join` instead of `subquery`  only if your business requirement allows.